# Lowest Common Ancestor visiting every tree node only once

Tags: algorithm

Can you say please, do we have a solution to find LCA of two nodes in binary tree visiting every tree node only once? Nodes only have left, right references without parent.
(O(n) time complexity).

Comment: Constant space doesn't seem reasonable. Can we use log space?

Comment: Can we assume the tree does not contain repeated values?

Comment: ou, i'am sorry: there is no requirement for memory. Tree can contain repeated values.